# Remmina 0.9.99.1 bug defaults to minimal quality settings - Workaround?

Tags: ubuntu, remmina

This is a known issue but I'm searching for a work-around. Link to the bug is noted below but in a nutshell, the GUI doesn't change the quality so you get stuck with something I can barely stand to look at.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...a/+bug/1345602

I note the last few lines of : ~/.remmina/remmina.pref
are:

```
...
vte_allow_bold_text=false
vte_lines=512
rdp_use_client_keymap=1
rdp_quality_0=0
rdp_quality_1=7
rdp_quality_2=0
rdp_quality_9=80
```

So, in theory if you knew what to set the quality settings above to, you could get a higher quality than the minimal setting.
Ideas anyone? Trial-and-Error hasn't been providing much in the way of predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

The work-around is that the same settings can be found and set elsewhere. Use the specific settings instead of the global ones and you have no trouble.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/216166/cant-change-remmina-quality